# How do I show a div when a textarea is focused and hide it when the textarea is blurred in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So my question is a bit more complicated then I could fit in the title. I am trying to recreate something like how trello does comments on cards.
On trello, when you click inside of the new comment textarea, the textarea expands and a div containing the "Submit Comment" link as well as a few other links for different actions shows (lets call this div the "links-div".

They simply do this by adding a "is-focused" class to the parent div of the "links-div" and handle the un-hiding via CSS.

Where I'm stuck is that if you click outside of the textarea (blurring it), the textarea shrinks back down and the "links-div" hides again **UNLESS** you click on one of the links inside  of the "links-div".

I want to recreate this and be able to click a link or submit button inside of my "links-div" without it hiding, but if I click anything outside of that "links-div", it should  hide as normal. How would I go about recreating this? Thanks.

Comment: I am a little confused—in your question title you wanted to hide the action elements when the textarea is no longer in focus, yet you want to not hide it when you mention it in your text. Which one do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Terry OP wants to hide the controls when the `textarea` is blurred, UNLESS the focus is moved to the "links-div" div.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a potential solution [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/noduhuqudo/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

This works by monitoring the `focus` and `blur` events on elements inside a `.comment` and toggling a class on the `.comment` itself.

When a `blur` event takes place on an element inside a `.comment`, we can use [`e.relatedTarget`](https://api.jquery.com/event.relatedTarget/) to find out which element has the new focus.  Then we can check if the newly-focused element exists inside a `.comment` or not.  If it does, we "cancel" the `blur`.  If it doesn't, we continue as normal.

HTML

```
<div class="comment">
    <textarea id="ta"></textarea>
    <div class="controls">
        <button>One</button>
        <a href="#">Two</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a href="#">This is outside the comment</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.comment .controls {
    display: none;
}

.comment.is-focused .controls {
    display: block;
}
```

Javascript / jQuery

```
// The selector ".comment *" will grab any element INSIDE a .comment
$('.comment *').on('focus', function () {
    // Whenever an element inside a comment gets the focus, give
    // its parent element a class
    $(this).parents('.comment').addClass('is-focused');
});

$('.comment *').on('blur', function (e) {
    var $newFocus = $(e.relatedTarget);

    if ($newFocus.parents('.comment').length > 0) {
        // The newly focused element is inside a comment (potentially
        // not the SAME comment - you'll want to fix this) so cancel
        // the blur
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }

    // The newly focused element is outside a comment, so continue
    // to blur this element and also remove our class
    $(this).parents('.comment').removeClass('is-focused');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the write up! After checking out your jsfiddle, i found that `e.relatetTarget` only works on mouse events, so it won't work on `blur`. But because of your answer, I was able to find a work around. Thanks!!

Comment: @oobie11 ?? Works fine for me... what browser are you using?  Internet explorer?  Then abandon hope... lol  Sorry for putting all that effort in.  IE should be banned from the internet.

Comment: Again, [another limitation of internet explorer](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/814285/focus-and-blur-events-should-have-relatedtarget), that all the other browsers do perfectly.  I'd say just redirect internet explorer users to the Chrome download page or something.

Comment: Lol, I'm using safari, didn't try in chrome and totally agree about IE. When I try your jsbin link it won't work though, not sure why?? Thanks again for the answer though.

Comment: Perhaps try in Chrome or Firefox?  I assume you're on an Apple device, using Safari?  It could also be a limitation of the device you're using.  Likely Apple hasn't authorised the use of the term "relatedTarget" for its users yet - they're probably waiting on a patent.

Answer (score 0):

So I got this working after going over the answer by @Alex McMillan. It is actually more simple than I was going about it. Instead of using the `.on 'focus'` and `.on 'blur'` events on the textarea, I used the `.on 'mousedown'` event on the document.

Here is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/h9ohkzdf/8/.

I may try and and use a containing div instead of the whole document and see if that works.